# How to pass variable to base class

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, inheritance, base-class

Consider the following Python code (Python 3):

- I have a class `Signal` comprising all the functions signals of all different kinds should be able to perform.
- For each kind of signal, I create a new class, where the data is "sampled", meaning an array with signal data is specified.

If I now want to plot the signal, the `plot` method of the `super()` class is called. However, in order to plot the data, the `Signal` class must somehow access it. Now my question is: What is the cleanest way to pass the signal data to the `Signal` class?

I have the feeling that there must be a better way than the `super().write_data(self.sample())` approach.

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Thu Jun 23 14:13:14 2022

@author: ilja
"""

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import math
import numpy as np


class Signal:
    def __init__(self, length):
        self.length = length
        self.data = None
        
        
    def write_data(self,data):
        self.data = data
    
        
    def plot(self):
        plt.figure(1)
        x = [i for i in range(self.length)]
        plt.plot(x, self.data)
        plt.show()
    
    
    def integrate(self):
        # TODO
        pass


class Harmonic(Signal):
    def __init__(self, periods, amplitude, frequency):
        super().__init__(int(2*math.pi*periods))
        self.amplitude = amplitude
        self.frequency = frequency
        super().write_data(self.sample())
    
    
    def sample(self):
        return [self.amplitude * math.sin(i*self.frequency) for i in range(self.length)]
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sig = Harmonic(7,3,1/2)
    sig.plot()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, since Harmonics is "based" on Signal, you can acces the attributes defined in Signal. You can simply write:

```
class Harmonic(Signal):
    def __init__(self, periods, amplitude, frequency):
        super().__init__(int(2*math.pi*periods))
        self.amplitude = amplitude
        self.frequency = frequency
        self.data = self.sample()
```

So, instead of

```
super().write_data(self.sample())
```

you write only

```
self.data = self.sample()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say, you should override the function `plot()` in `Harmonic` class.
Because the concept is:
You keep the common abstract idea in the base class, and go into specific implementation in the inherited class.
So yes, each signal has a `plot()` function. How to `plot()` a specific signal such as `Harmonic()` is a subject for Harmonic class not for the base class. Base class(`Signal`) only ensure that inherited class(`Harmonic`) has a basic implementation of plot().

```py
class Singal():
    def __init__():
        .
        return
    plot():
        .
        return
class Harmonic(Signal):
    def __init__():
        .
        return
    def plot():
        .
        return
```